# How to streaming video on HTTP using gstreamer and test using VLC player

Tags: gstreamer

i want the stream the video over HTTP and test using VLC but 
im unable to do HTTP video stream using  gstreamer

I have tried the below command 
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc is-live=true ! x264enc ! mpegtsmux ! hlssink
but unable to pass the  http address and test using VLC

gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc is-live=true ! x264enc ! mpegtsmux ! hlssink

I should be able to test using VLC or web browser

Comment: You still need a web server to host and provide the files `hlssink` creates to VLC.

Comment: using Gstreamer is not possible to stream http streams.. is it web server is needed to do this...